# How to loop a Z3 variable for adding constraints in python

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I want to loop a Z3 variable for adding constraints in python. Following code snippet might be helpful to clarify the problem I am facing.

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = [Int( 'b_' + str(i)) for i in range(10)]

s = Solver()
s.add(a <= 4)

for i in range(a): ################## How to do this? #####################
    s.add(b[i] == 1)

s.check()
s.model()
```

Comment: Probably change `range(a)` to `range(4)` or similar since a is a z3 Int object

Comment: This is an example. Let's say value of a is not known beforehand. Thanks for the comment. Let me rephrase the question for clarity.

Comment: Would `a` be solved at this point?

Comment: Variable a needs to he solved through other constraints. Every constraint should be in a single solver. There are dependencies. Hence sequential solving is not possible. I have a much complex version of problem. I havet tried to make a simplified representation.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. That's the whole point of a symbolic variable. It's value can be anything (subject to constraints you put in, of course), and thus it cannot be passed as an argument to `range`.

Since your `b`'s come from a list, you should instead iterate over that range. Something like:

```py
for i in range(10):
  s.add(Implies(i < a,  b[i] == 1))
```

Of course it depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve. Your question sounds like an instance of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). You might get a better answer if you ask about what you're trying to achieve, as opposed to how you can simulate `range` for a symbolic variable.

Comment: Great answer. I have solved issues like this for many cases. What to do in the following case? Implies( condition1 , for i in range(a): condition2)

Comment: Glad it helped. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for actions you can take on this answer; accepting an answer helps others who might have similar problems in the future.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it separately. (i.e., create a new question.) Comments are supposed to be used merely for small remarks/clarifications.

Comment: The issue is not yet resolved. What about the scenario: Implies( condition1 , for i in range(a): condition2)

Comment: As I mentioned; either "edit" your question to add a new variant; or start a new question. (Latter is better since questions with many different sub-questions are usually confusing to both readers and to people who try to answer them.) Comments aren't well suited for further discussions.